# Select List in Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I have multiple select statements that fetch result as list and I need to add this list finally to bind to a dropdown.Currently this is what I am doing..

```
 public void load()
{
    try
    {

        using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
        {
            var cm = (from c in db.COMPANY_MASTERs
                      select c).FirstOrDefault();

            if (Convert.ToBoolean(cm.PLANT))
            {
                var Div = (from vp in db.PLANT
                           select new
                           {
                               ID = vp.PLANT_ID,
                               NAME = vp.PLANT_NAME
                           }).ToList();
            }
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(cm.ANIMAL))
            {
                var Dep = (from vp in db.ANIMAL
                           select new
                           {
                               ID = vp.ANIMAL_ID,
                               NAME = vp.ANIMAL_NAME
                           }).ToList();
            }
            //this is what I am trying to do but cant,since the variables are nested                inside if.

              Div.AddRange(Dep);
            ddl.DataTextField = "NAME";
            ddl.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddl.DataSource = Div;
            ddl.DataBind();
}
```

This is my question,

**1.How can I overcome this anonymous type error and bind the added list to dropdown.**

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Actually,I am not able use AddRange,I need to add these list together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select, create a new instance of your `Variable` type, not an anonymous select :

```
var Div = (from vp in db.PLANT
           select new Variable()
           {
               ID = vp.PLANT_ID,
               GENDER = vp.PLANT_NAME
           }).ToList();
```

Then do the same with your Dep variable :

```
var Dep = (from vp in db.ANIMAL
           select new
           {
               ID = vp.ANIMAL_ID,
               GENDER = vp.ANIMAL_NAME
           }).ToList();
```

And you'll be able to `AddRange()`



**Edit :** Your variable need to be in the same scope to be used together.. You should declare them (strongly typed) up top of your function. (thanks andrii.litvinov)

```
List<Variable> Div;
List<Variable> Dep;
```

Comment: yes thanks,but what about the if statement?since both of them are inside a if how can i do AddRange?

Comment: Yes,thanks a lot,Is this the correct way of doing it?(AddRange) or am I doing something unwanted?

Comment: It is a correct way to do it. As always, there are many correct way to do it ;)

Comment: Got a problem related to this,when i bind the added list to dropdown the Textfield and value field are not found,gives error,please help? @Gabriel

Comment: Can't help without code.. And this looks like another question, so you should open a new one.

Comment: `ddlHostOrg.DataTextField = "GENDER";ddlHostOrg.DataValueField = "ID";
 ddlHostOrg.DataSource = Div.ToList();ddlHostOrg.DataBind();` this is what I am doing,binding the added list to dropdown

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482178/dropdown-datasource] please? @Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize `lstVar` and add the contents of the other two lists using successive `foreach` loops

Comment: I dont wanna use foreach for this

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Gabriel GM answer you should declare variables before first if.

Comment: Thanks a lot,but what am doing is that correct?I am just a newbie

Comment: No problem. It depends on what are you trying to achieve. You have not specified your question properly. And yes, you can use AddRange to merge two lists.