# DropDown datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

When I try to give datasource to dropdown it throws exception, I dono where am wrong,the control cant find the text and value field,when i dont give text and value fileds the value is binded as 'variables',can some one throw light for this.

```
 public void load()
{
    try
    {
        List<Variable> Div = new List<Variable>();
        List<Variable> Dep = new List<Variable>();
        using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
        {
            var cm = (from c in db.COMPANY_MASTERs
                      select c).FirstOrDefault();

            if (Convert.ToBoolean(cm.PLANT))
            {
                 Div = (from vp in db.PLANT
                           select new Variable()
                           {
                               ID = vp.PLANT_ID,
                               NAME = vp.PLANT_NAME
                           }).ToList();
            }
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(cm.ANIMAL))
            {
                Dep = (from vp in db.ANIMAL
                           select new Variable()
                           {
                               ID = vp.ANIMAL_ID,
                               NAME = vp.ANIMAL_NAME
                           }).ToList();
            }
            //this is what I am trying to do but cant,since the variables are nested                inside if.

              Div.AddRange(Dep);

            ddl1.DataTextField = "NAME";
            ddl1.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddl1.DataSource = Div.ToList();
            ddl1.DataBind();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
  public class Variable
 {
   public string NAME;
   public string ID;
 }
```

Comment: Well... what is the exception?

Comment: `DataBinding: 'CreatePass+Variable' does not contain a property with the name 'NAME'.` @KrisKrause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use property

```
public string NAME {get; set;}
```

Comment: yes,just now figured out that,am just a newbie to asp.net can you tell me what makes difference here?

Comment: public string NAME is a variable.
public string NAME{get;set;} is a property and the dropdownlist search   
from list of property of the datasource the fields text and value that it need.
read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx

Comment: Could you please tell me when I should use this get,set in my code @user3401335

Comment: Get and set permit to read and save a variable like using methods.
usually I prefer get and set when i need to do some operation before read and save this value or when in a class the property must me modified by third part. public string NAME {get; set;} in a shortcut. It could be more complex. Property could be read only or write only. With variable, if it is public, everyone can read and write. look this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk5e8eth.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Convert `NAME` and `ID` in `Variable` to properties. `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` look for properties rather than fields, in spite of their names.

```
public class Variable
{
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```